# How can I change the contrast of a picture using Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

How can I change the contrast of a picture using Silverlight?

Comment: Look at this question: [Adjust the contrast of an image in C# efficiently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115076/adjust-the-contrast-of-an-image-in-c-efficiently)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [.NET Image Tools](http://imagetools.codeplex.com) library is a good starting point. The ImageTools.Filtering namespace includes some filters that may do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but how about using layering and transparency; for example:

Rectangle { Background = black}
Image
Rectange { Background = white }

By changing the relative opacity of the image and foreground (white) rectangle, I would imagine you'd get a reasonable simulation of changing contrast.

Be interested to know if this works...

Comment: I'm not sure about that. In my case, I need to be sure, so no. But not a bad ideia.