# Can libjpeg be used to change contrast of images in C++?

Tags: c++, image-processing, jpeg, contrast

If not, where can I find the algorithm to adjust contrast of an image. I will have to code it in C++ and have access to libjpeg and libjpeg-turbo libraries

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_editing#Contrast_change_and_brightening

Is this a good starting point for color images?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I could have think of is the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) library, or [do it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115076/adjust-the-contrast-of-an-image-in-c-efficiently/3115178#3115178)*.

**<sub>* I know that the code in that answer is not c++, but if you know c or c++, you should be able to understand it.</sub>**

Answer (score 1):

You might like this one for starters: [Processing in the 8-bit YUV Color Space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

`C` there is the contrast adjustment. With an image with pixel format in YUV color space, constrast adjustment is quite easy and is an update for `Y` component of the pixel.

`libjpeg` is not quite the tool for image processing, unless you are decoding/encoding JPEGs and you need some processing on the way.